# How to decode protobuf obtained via axios using typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, axios, protocol-buffers, gtfs

I'm new to typescript, and I'm trying to understand how to use axios to download real-time gtfs data (which is in protobuf form). I'm getting an illegal buffer error when I try to run this code. I've posted the error in full below.

```js
import axios from "axios";
import * as GtfsRealtimeBindings from "gtfs-realtime-bindings";

const url = "https://www.rtd-denver.com/files/gtfs-rt/TripUpdate.pb";
export type RealtimeGtfsUrl = string;

export async function decodeRealtimeGtfs(
  url: RealtimeGtfsUrl,
): Promise<GtfsRealtimeBindings.transit_realtime.FeedMessage> {
  return await axios.get(url).then((response) => {
    return GtfsRealtimeBindings.transit_realtime.FeedMessage.decode(
      response.data,
    );
  });
}

const result = decodeRealtimeGtfs(url);
```

/Users/.../playground/node_modules/protobufjs/src/reader.js:47
throw Error("illegal buffer");
^

Error: illegal buffer
at create_typed_array (/Users/.../playground/node_modules/protobufjs/src/reader.js:47:15)
at create_buffer (/Users/.../playground/node_modules/protobufjs/src/reader.js:63:23)
at Function.create_buffer_setup (/Users/.../playground/node_modules/protobufjs/src/reader.js:64:15)
at Function.decode (/Users/.../playground/node_modules/gtfs-realtime-bindings/gtfs-realtime.js:134:34)
at /Users/.../playground/test.cjs:48:82
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

Comment: @Aluan why do you keep adding the [tag:javascript] tag?

Comment: @Phil because this question doesn't have much if anything specifically to do with ts. The JS answer and the TS answer will be exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

The response is in a binary format where Axios defaults to expecting JSON / plain text.

The decoder expects an [ArrayBuffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer) so all you should need to do is tell Axios what response type to expect.

Also, don't mix `await` with `.then()`; it just makes for confusing code.

```ts
export async function decodeRealtimeGtfs(
  url: RealtimeGtfsUrl,
): Promise<GtfsRealtimeBindings.transit_realtime.FeedMessage> {
  const { data } = await axios.get(url, { responseType: "arraybuffer" });
  return GtfsRealtimeBindings.transit_realtime.FeedMessage.decode(data);
}
```